# how to put foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I want to know how to use a foreign key in a table,

**I have a code here:**

```
create table penerbit_buku(
  id_buku char(8), 
  foreign key(id_buku) references buku(id_buku),
  id_penerbit char(3), 
  foreign key(id_penerbit) references penerbit(id_penerbit)
)
```

**Can I use this code instead:**

```
create table penerbit_buku(
  id_buku char(8) references buku(id_buku),
  id_penerbit char(3) references penerbit(id_penerbit)
)
```

I have tried both and it succeed, is that correct?

Comment: For performance on many-to-many tables, see [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, MySQL parses but **ignores** the standard inline `REFERENCES` syntax.

When you declare a foreign key along with an individual column definition, it accepts the syntax as legitimate SQL, but then does not store the foreign key constraint. There's no error reported, but it's as if you didn't write the foreign key syntax at all.

You must declare foreign keys as table-level constraints (your first example above).

This is a case where MySQL is missing a feature of standard SQL. The issue was reported back in 2004, but never fixed! https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4919

The reason for this issue is that historically, foreign key constraints were not supported by MySQL itself, but by the InnoDB storage engine, which was made by another company back then. They had to implement their own parser for CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE to support foreign keys, and they didn't feel like going the extra steps to support inline foreign key syntax, when table-level foreign key syntax would work.

The architect of InnoDB [posted](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13301) this response:

> [6 Sep 2006 10:03] Heikki Tuuri
>
> This will be fixed in MySQL foreign keys, when they are available for all table types.

The MySQL project is gradually working their way toward integrating foreign keys and similar features directly into the MySQL product. Perhaps in a few more years we'll see better support for standard FK syntax.

Answer (score 1):

EXAMPLE:

```
    CREATE TABLE Orders (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Number int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
    );
```

The foreign key must be referencing a primary key in another table

```
    create table penerbit_buku
    (id_buku char(8), 
    id_penerbit char(3), 
    foreign key(id_buku) references buku(id_buku),
    foreign key(id_penerbit) references penerbit(id_penerbit)
    );
```

I would need to see your other tables to give better help in the code

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_table1_table2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id`) REFERENCES `table2` (`id`);
```

Answer (score 1):

first lets look at the description of  `FOREIGN KEY`.

A `FOREIGN KEY` is a key used to `link` two `tables` together.

or

A `FOREIGN KEY` is a `field` (or collection of `fields`) in one `table` that refers to the `PRIMARY KEY` in another `table`.

Usually a table that has the `foreign key` is the `child table`. and the other table is the `reference` or `parent table`.

Since i Can not see your tables, ill give you different example.

Look at the following two tables:

```
Persons table:
Personal_id  LastName   FirstName  age

1            pretty       bob       20
2            angry        jack      30
3            happy        sue       28

Order Table:
OrderID OrderNumber Personal_id
1          77895      3
2          44678      3
3          22456      2
4          24562      1
```

Now look how `Personal_id` `column` in `Orders table` points to `Personal_id` in `persons table`.
The `Personal_id` in `persons table` is the `primary key` and the `Personal_id` in the `orders table` is the `FOREIGN KEY`.

now except `linking` how does `foreign key` help:

two general ways that i can think of:

1- foreign key is like a constrain that makes sure no action would destroy the links between tables

2- foreign key also acts as a constrain to stop invalid data from being inserted into the foreign key column, as it has to reference to the primary key column in the other table

code example in MySql:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Personal_id) REFERENCES Persons(Personal_id)
);
```

code example is SQL-Server/MS Access/ Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(Personal_id)
);
```

`Primary key` of `Orders table` is the `orderID`.

`Foreign key` of `Orders table` is what `links` it to `persons table`.

`Personal_id` `columns` are the columns that link both `tables`.

Both of the `code` chunks do the same depends what are you working with.

real world example:

```
assuming:
```

`customer_Table` `column` to be a `primary key` in `restaurant table` and `foreign key` in `orders table`.

if a waiter is putting `customer_Table` number 20 in the machine, and he puts `customer_Table` 200 by mistake such key does not exist as a `primary key` in `restaurant table` so he cant.

Extra:
what if you want to allow naming of the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, and define a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on many `columns`?

MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    Personal_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder FOREIGN KEY (Personal_id)
    REFERENCES Persons(Personal_id)
);
```